# I deleted the EFI volume where the Windows boot entry was while installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, uefi

I deleted the EFI volume where the Windows boot entry was. And I created a new EFI partition in the Ubuntu installation.
Now the only OS in my EFI partition is Ubuntu.
I have 4 drives :
/dev/nvme (UBUNTU) 500gb -> EFI partition here!!
/dev/sda (games) 1TB
/dev/sdb (WINDOWS 11) 500gb
/dev/sdc (games) 5TB
how can I set the Windows boot entry into the EFI ?

Comment: Can you still boot Windows from the GRUB boot menu?

Comment: Does the Windows drive have an ESP. I like to have an ESP on every drive, even though most systems seem to only want to use first drive. See the restore Windows bootmgr in IV. https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win Note if ESP not on first partition on first drive, you have to include the extra parameters to specify drive & partition of ESP. See also `man efibootmgr`

Comment: If you have no ESP with Windows boot files, you can only fix that by reinstalling Windows boot files. You then need a Windows repair/recovery flash drive or the Windows installer in repair mode.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, a way to solve this problem is creating an USB to boot a Windows installation, then you use the "Repair your computer" option, and then you use the option that let you get into the CMD and repair the Windows EFI Partition.

I would recommend you to search some guide when it show you how to repair the Windows EFI Partition, and then to add the Windows boot entry to GRUB, and then you will have everything going well.

Comment: wont that delete my ubuntu boot entry ?

Comment: I'm not totally sure about that. You can do a Backup of your Ubuntu EFI partition tho.